# Can I warp an overlap image using Sharp in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sharp, sharpjs

Is it possible to transform a composite image in Node Sharp that can achieve the below warp effect (desired final composite image on the right)?

[image]

I attempted using the affine operation but could not achieve the desired effect https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#affine

Comment: I think that the warping part is the tricky one and would require some knowledge of 2d transformations. The rotation and translation can be done, but you need to figure out the transformation matrix for the warp somehow.

Comment: Affine transformations preserve collinearity so it might not be possible directly, but if you translate every row by an offset to match the curve then it might be possible, but the sharp documentation doesn't mention pixel processing afaik.